# C# Including large readonly arrays in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

First off I'm new to C# and Windows Forms Programming. I've been a long time C embedded systems programmer.

I'm writing a Winform program that I need to include a large (48Kb) array of readonly data for simulation. I have it at the top of my Form1 class declaration, the problem being it continues for 1500 lines like so before I get to my public Form1() code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ScrollWave
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        readonly byte[] wvSamps = 
        {
            0x94, 0xa5, 0xca, 0x62, 0x41, 0x28, 0x4c, 0x93, 0x09, 0x42, 0x00, 0x25, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x04, 0x01, 0x40, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x70, 0x0d, 0x58, 0x3e, 0xc6, 0xd1, 0x07, 0x9c, 
            0x94, 0xa3, 0x8a, 0x62, 0x41, 0x29, 0x4c, 0x94, 0xc9, 0x32, 0x00, 0x24, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x04, 0x01, 0x40, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x70, 0x0d, 0x58, 0x3e, 0xc6, 0xd2, 0x08, 0x0c,
```

In 'C' I could just include it as an #include file so I didn't have to scroll down 1500 lines to get to the code I'm working on. How can I include large amounts of readonly data without having to put it at the top of my Form1 class declaration so I can avoid scrolling down 1500 lines to get to the code I'm working on? Thx!

Comment: You can have your array hardcoded in `public static class` but I suggest you serialize it using json and read it from json file.

Comment: why don't you create a separate static class for the byte[] that you are trying to use.. and create that class so that it will share the same namespace `ScrollWave`

Comment: Consider putting your data in a binary file and adding it as a resource. This will give you a `byte[]` property you can access called `Resources.wvSamps`. See [How to: Add or Remove Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bka19x4(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new class file named `ArrayData.cs` for instance and declare your data in that class as a static field:

```
public static class ArrayData
{
    public static byte[] WvSamps = {0x94, 0xa5, 0xca, 0x62, 0x41, 0x28, 0x4c, 0x93, 0x09, 0x42};
}
```

Then you can use it in your Form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public void DoSomethingWithData()
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < ArrayData.WvSamps.Length; i++)
        {
            //process your data here...
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, sorry, I'm a real noob at Visual Studio, I assume I would create this class in another .cs file and add it to my project. I'm using VS 2010 Express and I have tired and don't see how to add a file to my project. My learning is by reading Stephens C# Programming with Visual Studio 2010. Thanks for your help, if I can just get past some of this simple stuff I should be on my way.

Comment: @DaleH. just right click your project and select Add -> New Item. Then search for class, set a name and click Add button.